# What is causing this colour in my milk?

Tags: home-experiment

I was having a jar of water on my desk and I was adding a few drops of milk to it to see it's saturation point.

However after adding a few drops, I observed a bluish light in milk. I was wondered. After seeing the situation for a minute I saw I had a bulb lit on my desk. And the light was passing through milk too. However I am surprised at the phenomena and can't understand why it's happening. Is the light even associated or not? Can you give me some reason for this strange phenomena?

Answer (score 3):

You have discovered either  [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) or the [Tyndall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndall_effect). The former  is the  same effect that makes the sky blue. A few drops of milk in water is standard method of demonstrating the Tyndall effect in the classroom. The difference between the two effects has to do with the size of the scatterers, but the physical appearence is similar.